# If $U\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is open, then it is still open after multiplying with open ball radii

Tags: real-analysis

*The title could use some work - any suggestions are welcome.*

I have the following proposition that appears to be intuitively true, but I can't seem to prove it.

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ be open. Then we can pick for every $x\in U$ an $\epsilon_x \in (0,1)$ such that $B_{\epsilon_x}(x)\subseteq U$ and the disjoint union

$$U' = \bigcup_{x\in U} \{x\}\times (0,\epsilon_x)$$

is open in $\mathbb R^{d+1}$.

Is true? How can this be proven?

I figured if $\epsilon : U \to (0,1)$ is sufficiently continuous, then it would work. Maybe I can take $\epsilon_x$ to to be the supremum of all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, such that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq U$.
But for some reason I can't get it right even with either of those assumptions.

Comment: “If $U$ is open, then it is still open after multiplying with open ball radii” might be better suited for the (working) title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is open and as you said, it suffices to take $\varepsilon$ continuous. Lets assume that the boundary of $U$ is non empty ( which is only false in the trivial cases $U = \emptyset$, $U = \mathbb R^n$) then we can consider the function
$$ \varepsilon(x) = \frac{d(x,\partial U)}{2},$$
that is continuous at it is the distance to a closed set.
Due to the fact that $U$ is open, we have that $\varepsilon>0$ and 
$$ B(x, \varepsilon(x)) \subset U.$$
Then your union can be written as
$$U' = \{(x,a)\in U\times (0,\infty) |  a < \varepsilon(x) \},$$
which is open as it can be written as the intersection of open sets
$$U' = U\times (0,\infty) \cap g^{-1}((0,\infty)),$$
where $g$ is the continuous function
\begin{align*}
g:U\times \mathbb R &\rightarrow \mathbb R\\
(x,a) &\mapsto \varepsilon(x) - a.
\end{align*}